# How to protect other pages except login and signup from being access by an unauthenticated user in react js

Tags: reactjs

This is my App.js

```
const isAuthenticated = () => {
const token = localStorage.getItem('JWTtoken');
  return !!token;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='bg'>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navi/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={isAuthenticated()?<Home/>:<Navigate to='/login'/>}/>
        <Route path="/login" Component={Login}/>
        <Route path="/signup" Component={Signup}/>
        <Route path='/profile' Component={UserProfile}/>
        <Route path='/dashboard' Component={UserDashboard}/>
        <Route path='/admindashboard' Component={AdminDashboard}/>
        <Route path='/transactionhistory' Component={TransactionHistory}/>
        <Route path='/about' Component={About}/>
        <Route path='/loans' Component={Loans}/>
        <Route path='/loan' Component={Loan}/>
        <Route path='/loan approval' Component={Loan Approval}/>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

This what I tried but it doesn't work.
when I login and then page is redirected back to login page before the token could be stored in the local Storage.
I also tried using a sleep function but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple HOC, which checks is the user authenticated and redirect the user to other page:

```
const WithAuthentication = ({
  user,
  redirectTo = '/',
  children,
}) => {
   if (!user) {
     return <Navigate to={redirectTo} replace />;
   }

   return children ? children : <Outlet />;
};
```

EDIT: I received comment from HARI PRASATH V , who is pointing to the code of the OP and especially the function isAuthenticated. This code is not working okay, because:

1. The user is loading the page at path "/".
2. It is single page application and the component App is always loaded - in that scenario React is rendering first the component App.
3. When React render the component App, he see that there is Router. The path is "/". React Router check the element of path "/" which have function isAuthenticated().
4. The function isAuthenticated() is executed and returns false, since it is the first loading and there is nothing in the local storage.
5. Since we have false in the ternary condition, React renders component
6. The component Navigate changes the path to "/login"
7. React renders component Login.
8. Since there is no information about the code Login, I would suggest that there is form, where the user enters the credentials, makes request to some BE and receive token, which is stored in the localStorage. For example:

   ```
   const signIn = async () => {
      try {
       const response = await fetch(`${hostUrl}/user/login`, {
           method: 'POST',
           body: JSON.stringify(loginInfo),
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           },
       });

       if (response && response.ok) {
           const data = await response.json();

           localStorage.setItem('JWTToken', JSON.stringify(data));
           setUser(data);
           navigate('/');
       }
   } catch (error) {
       toast.error('Incorrect email or password!', {
           autoClose: 3000,
           pauseOnHover: false,
       });
   }
   ```

   };

And here is the key moment - the response with the JWTToken is received and it is set in the localStorage. I am pretty sure if the OP checks the localStorage the token will be there (I tested it :D). After setting the token in the localStorage, the function nagivate("/") navigates the to route "/", but the Router returns again the component Navigate and he returns the user to "/login" path. And here is the key answer - the App component never rerendered! Since the App component didn't rerendered, the function isAuthenticated is not executed again and the component for path "/" remains the same - .

For that I suggested component, which wraps the routes, which have to be protected.

I would want to mention that navigate("/") can be replaced with window.location = "/" and everything will work, but I do not think it is a good idea, since this is a SPA and SPA have to be developed in a way to not reload.

Comment: the problem is the isAuthenticated method is called before the token is set.Is there any way to delay the calling of isAuthenticated

Comment: React works in different way, for that I suggested correct and good way of doing the protection. I edited my comment and explained in details what is happening.